# Websphere Mq Connection error

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

When I run the following program it give me the jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect to queue manager '' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL. Can somebody please help me to run this program..

```
        MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

        // Config
        cf.setHostName("192.163.1.173");
        cf.setPort(1414);
        cf.setTransportType( JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
        cf.setQueueManager("TEST");
        cf.setChannel("SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");

        MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection("mgm","mgm321");
        MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///QUEUE4");
        MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
        MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);

        long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage("SimplePTP "+ uniqueNumber);

        // Start the connection
        connection.start();

        sender.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

        JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(10000);
        System.out.println("\\nReceived message:\\n" + receivedMessage);

        sender.close();
        receiver.close();
        session.close();
        connection.close();
```

This is the stack trace of the error..

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect to queue manager '' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL 'http://192.168.1.173', see linked exception for more information.
Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
    at  com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:578)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:214)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:408)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6398)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:5740)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:293)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:234)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6016)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6065)
    at IBMMessageSender.<init>(IBMMessageSender.java:32)
    at IBMMessageSender.main(IBMMessageSender.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:202)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2278;AMQ9516: File error occurred. [1=java.io.IOException[Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://192.168.1.173],3=http://192.168.1.173]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.internal.CCDT.parse(CCDT.java:344)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.internal.CCDT.<init>(CCDT.java:210)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteCCDT.<init>(RemoteCCDT.java:75)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.getCcdt(RemoteFAP.java:512)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1623)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1287)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:560)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:344)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://192.168.1.173
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.internal.CCDT$2.run(CCDT.java:313)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.internal.CCDT.parse(CCDT.java:305)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Look at the whole stack trace of the exception. What is the reason code in the com.ibm.mq.MQException?

Comment: I have update the stacktracce...., What i want is to send message to the queue in my localhost, Can you give me the exact steps for that task, i am so grateful

Answer (score 1):

The CCDT (Client Channel Definition Table) is a file that defines the properties of the MQ client connection. So this CCDT URL should reference this file.

Looking at your code it seems that you want to use JMS, so you are defining the connection properties on the JMS connection factory, in which case you don't need to set the CCDT URL.

But your JMS properties don't seem right either. You can find sample code under the MQ installation, e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\jms\samples\JMSProducer.java

Comment: I have run that source and it work fine when it run on local machine, but when I try to send message to a queue configure in different server machine it gives me he security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'IBM_MQ_TEST' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '192.168.1.173(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
Inner exception(s):    Message.. anyway greatful for you reply.